# Exception error when printing values from an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to pass values into my array using a 2.4 increment over each iteration in my loop. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RunningArray { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 

   double [] running = new double [10];

   int i;

   for (i=0; i<running.length; i+=2.4)    
      running[i]=i;    
      System.out.println(running[i]);

  }
}
```

But when I try to `print (running[i])` I am getting the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
>     at RunningArray.main(RunningArray.java:26)

Can someone please explain why?

Comment: that's because 2.4 * 10 > 10

Comment: @SergeyPauk Never gets that high.

Comment: Yeah, you're all reading it like it's Python. :-) The println is *after* the loop has run, when i has reached the loop limit. The i += 2.4 has nothing to do with it, it will throw an exception even with i++.

Comment: @carchelhf You are using a strange increment (2.4) to create values 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 for accessing an array and storing these values. What did you have in mind when you wrote 2.4?

Comment: @laune that was a short hint to the OP. Of course if one wants to be precise then one should say that `i` is incremented by 2 each time so it will trigger the exception when value will become as big as 10.

Comment: @SergeyPauk Being precise is being better :-)

Comment: @laune I'm trying to increment my loop so that over 10 passes I get up to the value 26. I've enclosed my "System.out.println(running[I]); and it has fixed the error. so thanks. It has also shown me how very far away I am from getting the results I want. :-/

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what you want, but maybe instead of `running[i] = i` you want `running[i] = 2.4 * i`? (and change `i += 2.4` to `i++` in the loop itself of course.)

Comment: Here is my assignment: "You train for 10 weeks, 
running an increasing number of miles per week, starting at running at least 2 miles your first week up to 26 miles by week 10. Create an array to show how many miles you increased each week."  running[i]=2.4*i got me closer, but it only goes up to 21.599999. I don't want the solution, but I am getting the feeling I am really far away from it, so any hints on how to get back on track would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The loop counter is fine, the real problem is that because you haven't enclosed `running[i]=i;` in braces, that's the only statement in the for loop. You're printing `running[i]` outside the for loop, so `i >= running.length` (10 in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Exception is self explanatory.  value of i  is going beyond array length of 10. Print the i value before accessing array value and you will know the issue.

Any reason for i = i+ 2.4?

At any point of time, i  should not cross array length of 10.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the variable i is of int type and each time you increment it by 2.4 only 2 is added to its value.

```
for (i=0; i<running.length; i+=2.4)    
System.out.print(i+", ");

Output: 0, 2, 4, 6, 8,
```

but just before the condition of loop is tested to be false, i is incremented by 2 making its value 10.
when you write the following line without braces it takes the last value of i, that is 10

```
System.out.println(running[i]);
```

Since running[i] for i=10 is not available it gives exception.

Write it like this

```
for (i=0; i<running.length; i+=2.4)    
{   running[i]=i;  
  System.out.println(running[i]);
}

Output:
0.0
2.0
4.0
6.0
8.0
```

Don't add 2.4 to the value of i, use another variable of double data type and increment it by 2.4 and store it in the array.

```
double [] running = new double [10];
 double d=0.0;
 for (int i=0; i<running.length; i++)    
 {
  d+=2.4;  
  running[i]=d;  
  System.out.println(running[i]);
 } 

output:
2.4
4.8
7.199999999999999
9.6
12.0
14.4
16.8
19.2
21.599999999999998
23.999999999999996
```

Answer (score -2):

you also are instantiating i as a int which means the .4 is being stripped each time. Initialize the variable to a double and it should carry the decimal point as you step through iterations.

```
 double [] running = new double [10];

 Double i;

 for (i=0.0; i<running.length; i+=2.4)
 {    
    running[i]=i;    
    System.out.println(running[i]);
 }
```

Comment: You can't use a double value for array indices